# What is the exact function of the 'export' bulliten?

Tags: bash

According to the BASH Reference Manual:

`export`

```
export [-fn] [-p] [name[=value]]

    Mark each name to be passed to child processes in the environment.
```

An example I've come across:

```
PS1=<\u\h \W>\$

export PS1
```

What I've gleaned from the documentation, and examples, is that export is used to permeate a change in the environment across multiple shells? My confusion comes form the numerous times I have not seen it used in similar circumstances, yet everything remains working as intended.

E.g, I created an environment variable to track the load order of my profile files. Here is an example from my .bashrc file:

```
PROFILE_ORDER="$PROFILE_ORDER:~/.bashrc"
```

and it produces this behavior

```
$ echo $PROFILE_ORDER
/etc/bash.bashrc:~/.bashrc
```

If my understanding of *export* is correct, then why didn't I need to use it in creating and modifying $PROFILE_ORDER?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

export is used to set variable which is accessible from a shell executed from your current shell.

```
> x=1
> export y=2
> echo $x $y
1 2
> bash
> echo $x $y
2
```

`.bashrc` is executed every time when you open new shell, so if I set `y=2` there, it would be known in every new shell without using `export`